# Wordpress - Display variable content based on variable in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, url, get

I have a wordpress platform and I am looking at displaying variable content on a page based on a variable in the url.

I have a 1 page website (www.vidlab.io) and i would like the section "GoPro Video Editing" to display information about GoPro video editing if the url is vidlab.io/?type=GoPro or information about wedding editing if the Url is vidlab.io/?type=wedding, and so on. I have read that you can use a get call, but not really sure how to have that information in the URL without getting a 404.

Any ideas on plugins to use? Or PHP that I can insert into the page to get this result?

Comment: If you try: `vidlab.io/?somethingelse=GoPro`, do you still get a 404? Some query string keys are "reserved" in Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is easy.

You have to use two Wordpress functions.

> add_rewrite_rule()

and

> add_rewrite_tag()

First you include the `add_rewrite_tag()` function into your `functions.php` of your theme.

For Example:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%food%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_tag('%variety%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

After that you have to choice one page of wordpress which contains your content. You have to use the page ID of this page.

Than you include the `add_rewrite_rule()` in your `functions.php`.

For Example:

```
 function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

**Notice!:**

After this you **have to** go to your `settings -> permalinks` and only push the save button to clean your permalink cache.

> IMPORTANT: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules
>   database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens,
>   Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any
>   changes.

My example is from the codex page of wordpress:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag