# Using database of main website for multiple subdirectories

Tags: wordpress

**I have a Wordpress website. I need to create subdirectories.

Purpose of subdirectories: I need to redirect the users into subdirectories based on their geo.

```
For example:

example.com – my website
example.com/uk – redirect users from UK.
example.com/usa – redirect users from USA
```

I have 6 pages and some posts on the main website and I need all these pages and posts in the subdirectories too with small changes in content.

Can I create all the sub-directories with a single database. Or it is mandatory to have a single database for all subdirectories.

**

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, any database will hold specific data.

eg: if you saved `I am a cat` in a table and it loads on `yourdomain.com` then created a page `home.php`, the page will always load with `I am a cat`.

With this in mind, if you copy `home.php` and create a new page `house.php` the call will still be to the same table 'I am a cat' the content will not change. any changes would affect everyone. (same as sub-directories with pages in there)

What you can do is change the language using one of several tools and plugins but the content will always be the same.

Haven, explained that, what else you could do is create other pages and load them separately.

Consider this thread with a similar request and solution.
[Wordpress - Display variable content based on variable in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515393/wordpress-display-variable-content-based-on-variable-in-url)

Let me know if it helps. It will be interesting to learn how this was solved.